# Difference between equals and colon in Java properties file

Tags: java, spring, properties

In spring, you can have different properties files in order to configure the messages, so they tend to be something like this:

```
message.key=text here
another.message.key=another text here
```

But today I saw in a project that it was using this format:

```
message.key:text here
another.message.key:another text here
```

I think this applies to any Java properties file, but what is the difference if any?

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties is worth a read

Comment: equals is in java, colon is in YAML...

edit oops already answered by someone else

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you were really talking about standard Java `Properties` files, there is no difference between a colon and an equals sign. Either can delimit a key from its value. In fact, you could even mix them in the same file, if you want to annoy readers.

Answer (score 5):

The documents are in different formats.

The first one is the normal properties format.

The second document is in the YAML language.

The YAML data will be translated to properties when used by Spring. So both formats have exactly the same result. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml

Comment: @erickson is correct; both are valid java.util.Properties formats, at least since JDK 1.2. See the documentation for java.util.Properties for details, but here's the money quote from JDK 1.7: "The key contains all of the characters in the line starting with the first non-white space character and up to, but not including, the first unescaped '=', ':', or white space character other than a line terminator."